Playing Bar on iPhone Lock Screen Shows Blank Play/Pause Icon and Missing Logo
I implemented code to display a media playing bar on the iPhone lock screen for my app. The functionality is mostly working—I'm able to see the playing bar, and the play/pause button is clickable.
However, there are two issues I'm encountering:

Blank Play/Pause Icon:
The play/pause button area is clickable and works as expected, but the icon itself is not visible. It appears blank, so I can't see whether it is showing the play or pause state.
Missing Logo:
I added a logo to the playing bar, but it does not appear on the lock screen.


Questions:

How can I make the play/pause button icon visible on the lock screen?
What could be causing the logo not to appear, and how can I fix it?

I would appreciate any guidance or insights on resolving these issues. Thank you!
func setupNowPlaying(_ player: AVPlayer) {
    let playerItem = player.currentItem
    var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "New Title"
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = 0
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = playerItem?.asset.duration.seconds
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player.rate
    if let image = UIImage(named: "image_here") {
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] =
            MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
                // Extension used here to return newly sized image
                return image.imageWith(newSize: size)
        }
    }
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState = .paused
}

func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared();
    
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(onPlayRemoteCommand))
    
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(onPauseRemoteCommand))
}

@objc func onPlayRemoteCommand() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
    self.playingBarView?.startPlayAnimation()
    self.audioPlay(status: true)
    return .success
}

@objc func onPauseRemoteCommand() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
    self.playingBarView?.stopPlayAnimation()
    self.audioPlay(status: false)
    return .success
}

